# xml Elements expanding to multiple lines

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a Xml file that looks like this: (part of the xml)

```
<timestamp>${timestamp}</timestamp>
    <registered>true</registered>
    <Person>
        <name>${name}</name>
        <age>${age}</age>
        <height>${height}</height>
    </person>
    ...
```

I am using Groovy XtmTemplateEngine to pass values to the xml

```
def engine = new groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(xmlFile).make(binding)
```

binding being a Map containing all the values i need to inject to the xml.The problem i am facing is that after injection the resulting file looks like this

```
<timestamp>
    ${timestamp}
</timestamp>
    <registered>
         true
    </registered>
    <Person>
        <name>
            ${name}
        </name>
        <age>
            ${age}
        </age>
        <height>
            ${height}
        </height>
    </person>
```

The values are injected as expected but the elements are expanded in multiple lines. Is there any way to revert the xml file to its initial  format, after having it processed with xmlTemplateEngine?

I tried pretty printing it using XmlUtils.serialize() but the result was the same.

EDIT:: As i didnt find any way to retain the original format of the file i ended up using SimpleTemplateEngine. As mentioned by daggett using <% %> had the same result as < gsp:scriptlet >

Answer (score 0):

seems no way to keep original formatting with XmlTemplateEngine

if you don't need xml validation and other features of XmlTemplateEngine try to use GStringTemplateEngine instead.

it keeps original formatting

```
def tpl='''
<root>
<timestamp>${timestamp}</timestamp>
    <registered>true</registered>
    <Person>
        <name>${name}</name>
        <age>${age}</age>
        <height>${height}</height>
    </Person>
</root>'''

def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(tpl).make([
    timestamp: new Date(),
    name: 'mama & mia',
    age: 12,
    height: 175
])
```

Comment: I really need to use <gsp:scriptlet/> and <gsp:expression/> that come with templateEngine. Maybe i just parse the file with XmlParser and add remove update nodes. Thanks dagget.

Comment: in GStringTemplateEngine you can use jsp-like tags `<% for(...) { %> ... <% } %>` instead of <gsp:scriptlet> and `<%= ... %>` instead of expressions.

Comment: Oh thats nice. Will work on it later on today and will report back.